# Show that the Area of a Triangle is Less than the Sector it is Inscribed in

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

In modern geometry (i.e. Hilbert axioms), how do we show that the area of $\triangle ABC$ is less than the area of the sector centered at $A$?  Is there a way to show it without calculus or analytic geometry?

Could we show that the area is less than or equal by saying that if $a$ is an interior point of $\triangle ABC$ then it is an interior point of the sector?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $AC$ has a length of $1$.  Let $\angle CAB=\theta$.  Then we have
\begin{align}
A(\text{triangle})&=\frac12\sin\theta\\
A(\text{sector})&=\frac12\theta
\end{align}

You are trying to show the inequality $$\sin\theta\leq \theta$$
which is *easy* using calculus.

You may also be interested in the circumscribed circle around a regular polygon if you want to take a geometric approach. But I do not believe that you can result on those axioms to make such a statement. If it is shown otherwise, I would gladly redact my answer.